# Querying in Laravel doesn't query the correct result

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do the following query model in Laravel:

```
$num_stamps = Groupsheetstamp::where('status', '=', 'active')
                                  ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
                                  ->whereGroup_sheet_id($sheet->id)
                                  ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($sheet, $user) {
                                      $query->where('original_group_sheet_id', $sheet->id);
                                  })
                                  ->get();
```

However, this still returns all groupstamps that have a `status` of `inactive`, and it completely looks over the where clause for `user_id`.

What am I doing wrong in the query model, since it isn't querying the correct result back?

An example output from the query could be the following, with `user id = 7` and `sheet id = 12`

```
"id" => 23
"group_sheet_id" => 12
"groupsheet_id" => 12
"group_id" => 3
"original_group_sheet_id" => 12
"user_id" => 1
"comment" => ""
"status" => "inactive"
"start_time" => "2017-03-16 17:09:06"
"end_time" => "2017-03-16 23:06:39"
"stamp_duration" => 6
"hours" => 0
"minutes" => 0
"themonth" => "03.17"
"manual_time" => ""
"created_at" => "2017-03-16 23:06:33"
"updated_at" => "2017-03-16 22:09:06"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what exactly result you're expecting. If you want to to search by group or by relation, you should use the closure. Just an example:

```
$num_stamps = Groupsheetstamp::where('status', 'active')
    ->where('user_id', $user->id)
    ->where(function($q) use ($sheet, $user) {
        $q->where('group_sheet_id', $sheet->id)
          ->orWhere('original_group_sheet_id', $sheet->id);
    })
    ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#parameter-grouping

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$num_stamps = Groupsheetstamp::where('status', '=', 'active')
                              ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
                              ->where('group_sheet_id',$sheet->id)
                              ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($sheet, $user) {
                                  $query->where('original_group_sheet_id', $sheet->id);
                              })
                              ->get();
```